# Storing luggage in Paris?

Tags: paris, luggage-storage

I’m travelling in Europe with 2 friends.

Currently in Paris. 
We would like to store our luggage in a locker because we have to leave our rental at 2pm and our flight for Amsterdam is at 8pm at Charles de Gaulle airport on Saturday.

We want to shop a last time.
If anyone has any advice ?

Comment: How are you getting to the airport? If by train, Gare du Nord has baggage storage lockers on the lower level. There's a security check and you need coins not bills (there is a change machine).

Comment: By train, with the state of emergency in Paris, I don't if the lockers are open for public

Answer (score 6):

Left-luggage services are available in a number of [Paris railway stations](http://en.parisinfo.com/practical-paris/getting-to-paris/from-train-stations/left-luggage-services-in-paris-railway-stations).

> Left-luggage services are available for the public in Paris railway stations : Gare du Nord, Gare de l’Est, Gare de Lyon, Gare d’Austerlitz and Gare Montparnasse. Luggage can be left for a maximum of 72 hrs and the cost, the same in all stations, ranges from €3 to just over €7 per day, depending on the size of the locker. They are available from 6.30am to 10.45pm. Warning: this service may be closed at any time for security reasons.

- Gare du Nord 18 rue de Dunkerque (10th)
- Gare de l'Est Place du 11 novembre 1918(10th)
- Gare de Lyon Place Louis Armand (12th)
- Gare d'Austerlitz 85 quai d'Austerlitz (13th)
- Gare Montparnasse 17 boulevard de Vaugirard (15th)

The site also provides links to several independent left-luggage services:

- [Gustave,](http://www.gustaveinparis.com/) Welcome City Lab, Tour Gamma A, 193 rue de Bercy (12th), Tel.. +33 (0) 6 89 25 13 82 support@gustaveinparis.com
- [Holibag](https://holibag.io/), 10 boulevard Diderot (12th) Tel.. +33 (0) 6 22 72 72 78 hello@holibag.io

An online service, [Eelway](https://www.eelway.com), 'collect[s] your luggage anywhere, anytime. Get them back when you arrive at the airport, train station, rental or hotel.'

Comment: @pnuts: they appear to be, if the SNCF info can be relied on http://www.gares-sncf.com/fr/gare/frpno/paris-nord/services/consignes-automatiques. The links to other options were included for that reason.

Comment: @pnuts: agreed, and the OP might share her experience, once she actually checks the multiple options.

Comment: I think I will use one of the left-luggage services like Eelway or Holibag

Answer (score 4):

I forgot to send a report about the service I ended up using. So I tried this Eelway's mobile luggage storage and it was quite simple & reassuring.

The concierge (as they are called) sent us a text an hour before arriving and collected our luggage at our rental. He sealed each bag and asked me to sign on his phone to confirm the seals numbers.

5 hours later at the airport, I met him at the rendez-vous point I received by email and by text. He was easy to spot with his branded yellow tee-shirt.

Another signature and done.

Very happy with this. I was a bit worried at the beginning but we had a chat for about 10 minutes about their start-up before leaving.